# Search a column to match data in another column and count the number of occurences

Tags: excel, formula

I've searched the web but I can't find anything specific for this.

I have column A as below, I need to search this column and find out how many occurrences there are of the data in column B, in the example below there a 4 (70011x3 + 70014x1).

```
A                        B
h323:70011               70011
70007                    70012
70011                    70013
h323:70014               70014
sip:70011@domain.com     70015
```

What formula would I need to use in Excel?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I don't know if there's a simple way to do this with a single worksheet function, but I could think of 2 methods I would use to accomplish this (and would love to see if any person could figure out how to do this in a single, simple, worksheet function I couldn't think of).

Either way, my solutions would be:

### 1) Use Array Formulas:

This would look as follows:

```
A                        B               C
h323:70011               70011          {=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,$A$1:$A$5,1)))}
70007                    70012          {=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,$A$1:$A$5,1)))}
...etc
```

Note that for this solution, **you have to type it in as an array formula** (Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>) at the end, but when you drag down column C and sum it up, you will get the correct total.
The challenge with this one is that it doesn't really give you the answer in one cell.

### 2) Use a Custom VBA Function (My Preferred method):

You can write your own VBA function to do this VERY EASILY.
The one I created was:

```
  Function MyFunc(CriteriaRng As Range, SearchRange As Range) As Double

  Dim CriteriaCl As Range
  Dim SearchCl As Range

  Dim RunningTotal As Double: RunningTotal = 0

     For Each CriteriaCl In CriteriaRng
        For Each SearchCl In SearchRange
        If InStr(1, SearchCl.Value, CriteriaCl.Value) > 0 Then RunningTotal = RunningTotal + 1
        Next SearchCl
     Next CriteriaCl

  MyFunc = RunningTotal

  End Function
```

All you can then do is in any cell type in `=myfunc(B1:B5,A1:A5)` and you will get the right answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'd prefer to use the custom method but I'm getting an 'Invalid Name Error' when trying to use the function, I've put your function into the 'VB' section of Excel, copied as it is

Comment: ... That's weird - I just copied and pasted EXACTLY what I typed for you and it worked just fine... To clarify, go into the VBA editor (I usually use `Alt`+`F11`, create a new module and paste in the code, then just put in the formula as I gave it in the solution - It works perfectly from my computer... Let me know what happens and, if still not, maybe it's your excel version or something...

Comment: Ah brilliant, it worked, I don't think I actually created a new module! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

the function `COUNTIF` takes wildcards.

with excel 2007, you can simply reference the whole column:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1&"*")
```

with 2003 or lower, you have to put the range in as cell references

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A2000,"*"&B1&"*")
```

note that numbers will have to be formatted as text, or you can add in the **countif** to cover numbers

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1&"*")+COUNTIF(A:A,B1)
```

You can then use a `SUM` on the column to get the total.